# I want to print the 31 business working day by comparing two days.it should print date in valid format

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am taking start date and end date. I am iterating from start date to end date based on working days once I cross 30th day I am breaking that condition and I want to print the exact 30th day. While I am printing the 31st date it's not giving valid format.it's giving below output:

```
31st date isjava.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1103308200000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Calcutta",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2004,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=51,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=353,DAY_OF_WEEK=7,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0] 31
```

below is my code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class DateDifferences_Validation {
    static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String startdate = "06/09/2004";
        String enddate = "18/12/2004";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        try
        {
          Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
          start.setTime(sdf.parse(startdate));
          Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
          end.setTime(sdf.parse(enddate));
          int workingDays = 0;
          while(!start.after(end))
          {
            int day = start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            if ((day != Calendar.SATURDAY) && (day != Calendar.SUNDAY))
            workingDays++;
            start.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            if(workingDays>30){
                System.out.println("31st date is"+ end);
                break;
            }
          }
          System.out.println(workingDays);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}}
```

Comment: Use the `SimpleDateFormat` to display the date.

Comment: i did like this also..      String d=sdf.format(end);
          System.out.println("31st date is"+ d);        it's throwing an error  Cannot format given Object as a Date

Comment: What is the valid format?  `end.getTime()` will give you out put as `Sat Dec 18 00:00:00 CET 2004`

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because the `end` object is a calendar, not a date. You need to obtain a Date object by calling `end.getTime()` which can then be formatted:

```
        if(workingDays>30){
            // Raw display
            System.out.println("31st date is "+ end.getTime());

            // Formatted display
            System.out.println("31st date is "+ sdf.format( end.getTime() ));

            break;
        }
```

Output:

```
31st date is Sat Dec 18 00:00:00 CET 2004
31st date is 18/12/2004
31
```

Comment: but, there i want to print 31 date only.... not end date.It's giving output as end date.

Comment: Just print the current date (meaning the current value of start) when workingDays=30.

Comment: it's working now ....    if(workingDays>30){
           start.getTime();
              System.out.println("31st date is "+ start.getTime());
              System.out.println("31st date is "+ sdf.format( start.getTime() ));
          break;

Answer (score 1):

it's working now,instead of passing end object we need to pass start object.`

```
if(workingDays>30){
                 start.getTime();
                 System.out.println("31st date is "+ start.getTime());
                 System.out.println("31st date is "+ sdf.format( start.getTime() ));
                break;`
```

op is:

```
31st date is Tue Oct 19 00:00:00 IST 2004
31st date is 19/10/2004
31
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Much easier with the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old classes seen in the Question.

Your rules are convoluted, but here is some untested example code that might be close to what you seek.

## ISO 8601

When representing date-time values as text, use standard ISO 8601 formats. For a date-only value, that would be YYYY-MM-DD.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

## `LocalDate`

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "2004-09-06" ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.parse( "2004-12-18" ) ;
```

Collect our resulting dates.

```
List< LocalDate > dates = new ArrayList<>( 31 ) ;  // Set initial capacity when known.
```

We can skip to next non-weekend-day either with our own code using an `EnumSet` with the `DayOfWeek` enum. We can then ask if the set contains the day-of-week of each incremented date.

```
EnumSet weekend = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
```

Loop those dates. In date-time handling, the Half-Open approach to defining a span-of-time is usually best. This means the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

```
LocalDate ld = start ;
while( ld.isBefore( stop ) && ( dates.size() <= 31 ) ) { // If within date-range, and not over 31 days collected. 
    if( dates.size() != 30 ) {
        if( weekend.contains( ld.getDayOfWeek() ) {
            // Do nothing. Let the date get incremented below.
        } else }
            dates.add( ld ) ;
        }
    } else {  // if 30th, add, ignoring rule about skipping weekend.
        dates.add( ld ) ;
    }

    // Setup the next loop.
    ld = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;
}
```

### *ThreeTen-Extra* library

Tip: Instead of making an `EnumSet` for weekend, you can use the `TemporalAdjuster` implementation [`nextWorkingDay​()`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Temporals.html#nextWorkingDay--) found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

```
LocalDate nextWorkingDay = myLocalDate.with( org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDay​() ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).